# Spring dev tool class is not found at run time

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have created a SpringBoot app which has spring-boot-devtools in Maven pom

I can run it without issue in Intellji. But if I run it from the jar being built, it throws the following exception. It gives the following exception. It looks like the devtool jars are not packaged?!

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.x.x.x.TestApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/filewatch/FileChangeListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devtools is excluded from a packaged jar by default to avoid it being accidentally used in a production deployment. If you want to include Devtools in your packaged jar you can opt-in. To do so, set `excludeDevtools` to `false` in your plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```